# Как построить sql дерево?

Tags: mysql, sql

Превед всем!
Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE `hers` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `parent_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=0
;
```

В которой есть инфа:

```
id  name    parent_id
1   her1    NULL
2   her2    1
3   her3    1
4   her4    2
5   her5    4
6   her6    3
```

Вопрос: Как мне построить дерево одним запросом без созданий таблиц, view, etc? Например, как найти коренного родителя для id = 5 ? И как, например, для него же найти не коренного, но второго (после коренного) потомка? Чтоб результат выглядел примерно так:

```
id
1
2
4
5
```

Comment: При такой организации таблицы - никак, только если замените список соседства, скажем, на вложенные множества, тогда дерево можно будет извлечь одним запросом.

Comment: @cheops , гениально! Оказывается, в этой дурацкой таблице автор предусмотрел колонки lft и rgt , это просто я слабоумный не понимал для чего они ^_^ Только почему-то колонки level у него нет, но то что мне нужно и без неё можно получить. Кому интересно: http://zabolotnev.com/mysql-nested-sets и http://www.getinfo.ru/article610.html

Comment: Потому что считается, что level вы всегда можете вычислить, иногда его вводят, чтобы кэшировать результат, но если ресурсы позволяют, надежнее вы вычислить. В каноническом варианте хранят только левую и правую границы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как посоветовал @cheops , можно с помощью **NESTED SETS** , в моём случае это приемлемо. Отличные маны с примерами: http://zabolotnev.com/mysql-nested-sets и http://www.getinfo.ru/article610.html

Answer (score 0):

`adjacency list` и, судя по `ENGINE=InnoDB` - mysql в качестве СУБД?

Ответ - никак.

Не одним запросом, а кучкой, но всё равно на уровне SQL - можно поизвращаться с хранимыми процедурами. Но mysql и хранимые процедуры... Это довольно печальная тема.

Лучше поменяйте или СУБД или модель хранения дерева. Из СУБД посмотрите на postgresql (помимо рекурсивного `CTE` для решения вашей задачи в лоб, есть даже специальный [ltree](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html) для хранения деревьев). Из моделей деревьев - `Nested Set` или `Materialized Path` - у каждого есть свои сильные и слабые стороны и какой-то из них рекомендовать как серебряную пулю невозможно. Посмотрите, какое лучше подойдёт для вашего случая.

Comment: К сожалению, сменить СУБД невозможно. Видимо придётся либо делать какое-то view, либо процедуру :(